# Splunk-Dashboard - how to add links as field in table visualization?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-dashboard, splunk-formula, splunk-calculation

I'm sending as a - payload.url field - some link for each event,
but in the dashboard - table it's appeare as text and not as link.

maybe someone tried to do it?

i've added - [Visit example website](https://www.example.com)
the  tage into the payload and try to sent it in two ways:

1. `<a href="https://www.example.com">Visit example website</a>`
2. `"https://www.example.com"`

both are appeare as text and not as links.

Comment: what have you tried? Ie, what does your dashboard look like now (a screenshot would be helpful), and what does the XML underneath look like?

Comment: I've tried to work with the Splunk documentation about  DrillDownLink to URL. but it didn't get me anywhere, about the screenshot it's a bit problematic for security reasons to expose but I can say that is just a table that one of the column values is URLs,
but when you click the URL is just reads it as text and not as a link.

Comment: Please share the sanitized dashboard XML.

Comment: Duck Duck Going got me https://community.splunk.com/t5/All-Apps-and-Add-ons/How-do-I-make-a-clickable-hyperlink-in-search-result/m-p/438278 (the Stack Overflow-like site unfortunately has none of Stack Overflow's curation policies, so it's full of junk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks all, what I needed to do is - add this:

```
<drilldown>
     <link target="_blank">$row.URL|n$</link>
</drilldown>
```

found it here - https://community.splunk.com/t5/All-Apps-and-Add-ons/How-do-I-make-a-clickable-hyperlink-in-search-result/m-p/438278
thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what your dashboard looks like (a [sanitized] screenshot, XML, etc), we can only *guess* at what you're trying to do

That said, if you're wanting to do what I *think* you want to do, put the following in its own `panel` on your Dashboard (you'll need to do this from the Edit Source option):

```
{top of dashboard}
<row>
  <panel>
    <html>
      <li><a href="https://some.url/path">link text</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://other.url/path/to/link">text of link</a></li>
    </html>
  </panel>
</row>
{bottom of dashboard}
```